# Django Heroku Deploy: OSError: [Errno 2] No Such file or directory: '/app/{appname}/assets'

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I've found similar questions but they were from years ago and the solutions haven't worked so far.

Here's the traceback:

```
(devtm) λ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
Running python manage.py collectstatic on ⬢ {appname}... up, run.1335 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 115, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 397, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/{appname+"site"}/assets'
```

Here's my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets/css'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets/images'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets/js'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets/venue_images')
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I've tried adding a directory (with blank file for git) named `staticfiles` to my root (so next to the `manage.py` file). I've tried adding a folder/file named `assets` in the folder with the `settings.py` file, which appears to be where the traceback is indicating the error. I've also tried pathing without the `..` portion and without the `../{appname}+"site"` portion.

This is my first attempt at launching a Django site on Heroku and I've been struggling for more than a week on this. I've read tons of documentation and SO posts, but haven't been able to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are not being manipulated based on output. They are quoted. 
Try changing where applicable, example:
Note:
I have no idea what appname is, if it's a variable or literal.

Try changing the below statement and others similar to
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname+"site"}/assets/css')
To:
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../{appname'+'site' +'}/assets/css');